# How to enable flow checking on vscode for react-native?

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code, flowtype

### Goal

Be able to create a new project for react-native (using `react-native init`), and enabling flow checks on Visual Studio Code.

### What I Did

I just created a new react-native project

```
react-native init iaptris
```

then opened Visual Studio code

```
cd iaptris
code .
```

I saw this errors

[image]

Whis these error descriptions (in italian, sorry)

[image]

Googling I concluded I must install [Flow Extension for VsCode](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-for-vscode) and I did.

I then disabled native checking for current workspace, setup file association and path to flow command

```
{
  "javascript.validate.enable": false,
  "files.associations": {
    "*.json": "json",
    "*.js": "javascriptreact"
  },
  "flow.pathToFlow": "C:\\Users\\mirko\\.vscode\\extensions\\flowtype.flow-for-vscode-1.0.1\\node_modules\\.bin\\flow.cmd"
}
```

Closed and restarted vscode on same workspace

### The problem

At this point, errors disappeared, but also, removing a curly brace to throw a new syntax error, I do not see any errors. No errors.

[image]

### Question

**What else must I do now?**

Comment: You must read the official docs https://flow.org/en/docs/getting-started/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actual solution, please post your answer if this is not the better method. And I think it's not the better method.

1. `react-native init <project name>`
2. open VsCode
3. disable `Javascript -> Validate` *for the current workspace only* (sorry if next image is in italian, but it's enough as reference)

[image]

4. install a plugin

   ```
   yarn add eslint babel-eslint eslint-plugin-flowtype --dev

   or

   npm install eslint babel-eslint eslint-plugin-flowtype --save-dev
   ```
5. create a `.eslintrc` with following content

   ```
   {
     "parser": "babel-eslint",
     "plugins": [
       "flowtype"
     ],
     "extends": [
       "plugin:flowtype/recommended"
     ]
   }
   ```
6. close and reopen vscode and the workspace